# Как устроена передача данных в Java через Socket и ServerSocket?

Tags: java, сокет, сеть

Когда я передаю конкретный байт

```
OutputStream socketOut = socket.getOutputStream();
socketOut.write(0);
```

он сразу отправляется. 
Насколько мне известно, байт в итоге будет запакован в IP-пакет. И мне не нравится, что для каждого отправленного байта будет сделан отдельный пакет. Разве их нельзя поместить в один?
Я думаю, у меня неправильное понимание. Объясните, как всё устроено на самом деле.

Comment: А что мешает писать сразу все данные в метод  write()?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вы не понимаете, что такое Сокеты. В вашем примере кода вы отдаете не один байт\бит, а целый стрим, который может состоять из большого количества байт.

Далее, сокеты делятся на два основных типа — TCP и UDP и у каждого из них свои особенности:

TCP:

- Использует принцип соединений
- Гарантирует доставку и очередность
- Автоматически разбивает информацию на пакеты
- Следит за тем, чтобы не пересылать данные слишком интенсивно
  (контроль потока данных)
- Легко использовать — как запись/чтение из файла

UDP:

- Не использует принцип соединений — придется реализовывать это вручную
- Не гарантирует доставку и порядок доставки пакетов — они могут дойти
  в неправильном порядке, с дубликатами, или вообще не дойти!
- Нужно вручную разбивать данные на пакеты и отправлять их
- Нужно следить за тем, чтобы не пересылать данные слишком интенсивно
- Если пакет потеряется, то нужно как-то это отследить, и в случае
  необходимости переслать его заново

В вашем случае используется TCP. Другими словами, вам не зачем беспокоится о корректности доставки данных.

Answer (score -1):

> И мне не нравится, что для каждого отправленного байта будет сделан
>   отдельный пакет. Разве их нельзя поместить в один?

Можно. Именно для этого и придуман алгоритм Нагла, который включен для всех сокетов по умолчанию.